# Setting unique timers in for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, timer

I am using a for loop and setting a timer at the beginning, and ending it at the end. The for loop repeats 3 times and gives me the 3 values that I need but I want to be able to compare the timer values it gives me in java and compute the results for biggest-smallest. To do that, I need each timer to have a unique name which I cannot seem to do. Here is an example of my code.

```
int j;
for(j=1;j<=3;++j){
    //...code
    {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime(); //timer start
        //...code
        long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime; //timer end
        System.out.println(startTime + "_1");      }
        {
            timer comparison for the 3 timers
        }
```

As I said, I already have the values, but I need a way to compare them. "estimatedTime" is the value I'm comparing, so ideally I like to assign names "estimatedTime2" and "estimatedTime3" on the second and third values.

Comment: Always a good idea to include a tag for the language you're using

Comment: use your indexer to index an array where you will put your timer results.

Comment: Spring, Guava and commons-lang all have a `StopWatch` class. That may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a variable with a different name "on the fly", so you will have to save the estimated time in an array or other data structure (e.g., a list) and index accordingly.

For example, you could do:

```
    long[] times = new long[3];

    for (int j=0;j<3;++j) {
    //...code
    {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime(); //timer start
        //...code
        times[j] = System.nanoTime() - startTime; // times[0], times[1], times[2]
        System.out.println(startTime + "_1");      }
        {
            // timer comparison for the 3 timers
        }
    }
```

After the loop completes execution, you will have all the 3 time estimations in the `times` array.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this got it working. I'll have to fully test it later